# Touch screen with Raspberry Pi

Tags: touchscreen, screen, spi

I have a [240x320 2.8" touchscreen](http://www.ebay.com/itm/191531963190), with "driver IC: ILI9341". It seems to use a SPI interface. How to connect it to the Pi (which pins to which pins of the GPIO?) and how to use it, e.g. from Python to display some text?

[image]

Photo of the screen itself:

[image]

Comment: As a minimum you need to find the model number of the display driver chip and add that information to your question.  Don't expect others to follow links to find relevant information.

Comment: I added the reference @joan : Driver IC: ILI9341.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar display for one of my projects. 
As for the jumper wires, i connected them like this:

- Voltage at the Common Collector (vcc) -> pin 1;
- Ground (gnd) -> pin 6;
- Chip Select (cs) -> pin 24;
- Reset -> pin 16;
- Data Command (DC/RS) -> pin 15;
- Serial Digital Interface (SDI/MOSI) -> pin 19;
- Clock (SCK) -> pin 23;
- Light Emitting (LED) -> pin 17;

I also used this library to draw and display: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ILI9341

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot @ilyabogackiy. I will test that this evening. As I can see this Python code only offers display, but no "touch" (or am I wrong?). What do you use for touch ?

Comment: You are right. But unfortunetaly, my project has no touch functionality, only drawing and display. But you can try this library: https://github.com/BLavery/lib_tft24T There will be need for additional wiring logic though, make sure you read https://github.com/BLavery/lib_tft24T/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post but I have the same LCD and used Brian Lavery's python driver as suggested in the comments above. I modified his code a bit to make it work "better". If anyone is interested with some step-by-step guide, you can read it at https://behindthesciences.com/electronics/connecting-ili9341-SPI-TouchScreen-lcd-to-a-raspberry-pi-in-python/

Happy programming! :)